# Django on Heroku - missing staticfiles manifest.json file

Tags: python, django, heroku, django-staticfiles, whitenoise

I am trying to start Django on Heroku. I looked around Stack Overflow, I tried different things, but I cannot figure it out. It looks similar to all the questions related to staticfiles problem on Django, unfortunately I don't know where the problem is. My project runs just fine with `DEBUG = True`, but when I change it to False, I get following traceback:

`2020-11-09T13:13:42.801384+00:00 app[web.1]: Missing staticfiles manifest entry for 'order/css/open-iconic-bootstrap.min.css'`

It happens on all of my apps that require staticfiles. I tried to find manifest.json, but it does not exist. So I think this is the issue.

Here are my relevant settings:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
#more ...
]
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles') 
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedStaticFilesStorage'

django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

Thanks for looking into this!

Comment: Can you confirm that you already tried with `heroku run python manage.py collectstatic` ? Do you have DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC enabled on you settings ? If yes, disabling it might give you a lead on what's going wront. Maybe set DEBUG_COLLECTSTATIC=1 as well.

Comment: @keoma here is my configuration:
`DEBUG_COLLECTSTATIC:   1`
`DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC: 0`. I tried toggling DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC, but I could not see any difference. When I run collectstatic on heroku, I get
`It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path`
on all of my files resulting in 
`0 static files copied to /app/staticfiles, 742 unmodified, 2140 post-processed`

Comment: there might be a difference between `DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=0` and the variable not being set. Can you try with `heroku config:unset DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC` ? Make sure the run build script and not just restart the script too.

Comment: @keoma That worked! Can you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 2):

@keome in the comments already gave you the first steps in debugging this issue so I won't repeat that here.

Notwithstanding the issues they raised (which should be looked at first), I think the key issue is that your whitenoise configuration isn't set up to generate a manifest. You probably want:

```
# Serve compressed and manifested static files
STATICFILES_STORAGE = "whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage"
```

The reason your current configuration would work with `DEBUG=1` is that in debug mode, django will fall back to serve static files itself (neither secure nor efficient).

Second, make sure that you run `collectstatic` with the same storage configuration as you're running the server - I cant see what settings files you have, but it seems like you've collected static without a manifesting strategy, but you're trying to serve it *with* a manifesting strategy (and hence django is confused by why there isn't a manifest).

Incidentally, whitenoise by default creates a `staticfiles.json` file, not a `manifest.json` file, and it's served as a static file. So if your `STATIC_URL = "/static/"` then you can find the manifest at `<your-domain>/static/staticfiles.json`.

#### Edit - clarification

The reason the manifest of staticfiles isn't actually called `manifest.json` is because that'd conflict with the usual name of the `manifest.json` served as part of a Progressive Web App ([spec here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Manifest)), which is kind of similar (in that it can serve as an instruction to the browser of where to find certain files) but not the same.

Comment: I have the STATICFILES_STORAGE line above, but I'm getting all the same symptoms. I can reproduce locally by setting DEBUG=False and doing collectstatic. I can see all the files in staticfiles, but Django is not serving them up (400 errors). Ideas of how to debug?

Comment: I had not properly installed whitenoise. (I forgot to add the middleware.)